# Why doesn't YamlDotNet serialize private fields of the class?

Tags: c#, yamldotnet

I tried to find the answer on the Internet, but without success. Instead, several times in different posts I've met the phrase that “private fields … will never be serialized”. So I guess this is not a bug but a philosophy.

I do not understand this, however. How can a class be serialized and then restored back without the private members responsible for the class's internal logic?

Comment: It is a decision of the developer to code a serializer using properties. You can write your own using only fields or using a method.

Comment: BTW I never had any problems with that convention, because I like the SRP

Comment: @SirRufo, I speak C++ for almost 25 years, but now I got a C# project that includes serialization. These languages vary a lot despite the similar syntax, and my habits may be wrong. I guess that the "SRP" stands for "Single Responsibility Principle", but I do not see how it is related to the issue.

Comment: There is no issue at all. The developer/s of YamlDotNet made a decision. Thats it. If you do not like that decision, do not use their library. SRP: I have special DTO classes for serialization and only for that purpose and I even have special classes for different serialization kinds (Json, Csv, ...)

Comment: And YamlDotNet is a library for low level parsing and emitting of YAML. It is not a „you can serialize any class to YAML“ library. The main issue is your expectation what this library might be

Comment: @SirRufo It's not about what I like or dislike. I requested for an explanation. And your statement about the low level of YamlDotNet does not correspond to what its creator writes about his library. DTO is irrelevant in my case, since my project has nothing to do with remoting.

Comment: Who can give you the real explanation why the developer/s made that decision? Only the developer/s themself. We cannot read their minds. To get the real explanation ask the developer/s of YamlDotNet

Comment: As the author of YamlDotNet, I have answered the question, but I am not sure that this is a good question for Stackoverflow, as it is mainly opinion based. I have still tried to provide an answer that may be useful for others.

Comment: @SirRufo YamlDotNet is not only a "library for low level parsing and emitting of YAML". Where did you get that impression ? It is also an object serialization library, similar to YamlDotNet. In fact I would say that most users of the library use it for serialization.

Comment: @AntoineAubry It is a cite from https://aaubry.net/pages/yamldotnet.html and your answer proove my second part „It is not a you can serialize any class to YAML library“. BTW I never said it is **only**

Comment: @SirRufo, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. Basically I wanted to point out that the statement "It is not a „you can serialize any class to YAML“ library." is false. Most of the library is actually about serializing and deserializing arbitrary objects to YAML. In the page that you quoted, it is in the same paragraph: "A serialization library is also included that allows to read and write objects from and to YAML streams."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why YamlDotNet serializes only public properties by default is because doing otherwise would break encapsulation. Accessing private members would mean that the model would be unable to guarantee its invariants. If you compare with other libraries, such as Json.NET, you will notice that they use the same approach.

I don't think that this is a problem because you should not be (de)serializing your domain model directly. Doing so would constrain your domain model to your serialization schema, which in many cases will need to be different. That's the same problem as trying to map your domain model to a relational database.

Instead, you should define a serialization model and map between your domain model and that serialization model. In that case there's no need to serialize private fields.

That said, if you really want to serialize private fields, that's trivial to do. You need
register you own implementation of [`ITypeInspector`](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Serialization.Serializer) that returns private fields. You can base your implementation on [`ReadableFieldsTypeInspector`](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/TypeInspectors/ReadableFieldsTypeInspector.cs).

Comment: I still don't quite understand. I always considered serialization as a part of the class' implementation; the user can request for the class' serialization only by calling some public method of this class or some dedicated internal class. I do not see how this can breake incapsulation, since the class' users still have no access to private fields. Could you please elaborate your note about ITypeInspector, or give a link to an example? And an another question: the method Deserialize(TextReader input) returns a dictionary; what exactly is the key of this dictionary?

Comment: In YamlDotNet, as in most serialization libraries that I am aware of, the serialization is decoupled from the class. This is why accessing private members of the class would break encapsulation.

Comment: @Ilia Regarding ITypeInspector, this issue contains an example: https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/424

Comment: @Ilia Regarding the Deserialize method, there are multiple overloads. One generic and another that returns object. I assume that you are referring to the later. If you don't indicate which class you want to deserialize to, by providing the generic argument, or by passing a `System.Type` instance, you will get an object of the type that corresponds to the YAML node that you are deserializing. If the node is a mapping, the corresponding .NET type is `Dictionary<object, object>`. The keys and values of the dictionary will contain the keys and values of the mapping, respectively.

Comment: Thank you Antoine, you helped me very much. As I mentioned in one of my previous comments, I came from C++ area, and many things seem to me strange. I written the first in my life line of C# code approx. a month ago.